# Codeigniter numeric regex including dot and comma

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter framework.

My validation rule like that

```
array(
    'field' => 'amount_per_unit'
    'label' => __('Cost'),
    'rules' => 'trim|numeric|required|greater_than[0]'
)
```

it works for numbers which contains dot. In my country we use dot(.) and comma(,). I want to change codeigniter regex for dot and comma.

This is codeigniter regex

```
return (bool)preg_match( '/^[\-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$/', $str);
```

if i enter number which has dot it returns true, but if enter number which has comma it returns false but it should return true.

how can i change the regex for including dot and comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a character class to include both characters. I'd write this as follows:

```
return (bool) preg_match('/^[-+]?\d+(?:[,.]\d+)*$/', $str);
```

Regular Expression:

```
^          # the beginning of the string
[-+]?      # any character of: '-', '+' (optional)
\d+        # digits (0-9) (1 or more times)
(?:        # group, but do not capture (0 or more times):
  [,.]     #   any character of: ',', '.'
  \d+      #   digits (0-9) (1 or more times)
)?         # end of grouping
$          # before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

Comment: thanks it worked. It worked for "15250,00" but i did not work for "15.250,00". it should work for "15.250,00"